# Possible to bypass lax, strict, skip processContents settings when performing schema validation in java?

Tags: java, xsd, schema, sax, xml-validation

I have an XSD Schema which has the following element

`<xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" />`

The idea is to have different XML content inside that element which might match to different schemas.

I'd like to be able to validate the contents of the xml coming in place of that element against a list of xsds to make sure what I am receiving is valid and to top it off I cannot modify the actual xsd schema myself.

Because of the lax processContents flag the message will always come out as valid regardless of whether it matches against one of the xsds in the list or not.

Is there any way that I can override/ignore this flag at validation time so that I can choose to perform strict validation in certain places if I want?
I have looked at Sax Parser validation and JAXB transformation with validation but neither seem to allow me to control the validator in such a way that it ignores the lax flag without me actually having to perform changes in the xsd itself.

Comment: You're asking to ignore the assertion to ignore?  Effectively, you'd have to provide a replacement content model.  Why not simply validate against a different XSD containing that replacement content model?

Comment: By replacement content model you mean a different xsd of my own which looks almost the same except does not have the lax flag? If thats the case, yes it would be possible although it would add yet another xsd to keep track of when and if the original ever gets changed introducing potential future mistakes. I fail to understand why is it so difficult for the parsing engine to provide control over such a simple feature on a message by message basis.

Comment: By replacement content model, I was generalizing to include not just changes to `xs:any/@processContents` but to any sort of more strictly specified content in place of`xs:any`.  It's not that it would be difficult to for a parser to provide such an override, it's that it's hard to image widespread demand for it.  If you really need to often apply two XSDs that differ in only minor ways, and if you can't use `xsd:override` to help, you might consider simple XSLT transformations from the authority XSD to the derivative variants.

Comment: Yes I thought of xslt but once again it sounds like adding more complication (Plus performance hit for the xslt transform) for something so simple. I guess I'll dig further into this. Thanks

Comment: why not modify the schema "on the fly" before loading it into the validator?  that way you don't need to maintain a second schema which could get out of sync with the original.